# Toilet for Mermaid?

Tags: science-based, technology, fantasy-races, merfolk, furniture

I want to know a kind of toilet design for a mermaid, considering they live surrounded by water and they poop through the anus (or whatever the organs name is) that is located in the front rather than the rear side.

- I want to know a toilet design for a mermaid, so a comment or answer that just says that they wouldn't use such a thing and poop wherever they want is out of the question, because to me its just ditching the question.
- I'm considering the spaceship toilet type, but I'm not sure it can work or is  hygienical and safe enough if it is surrounded by water. Also there is the non conventional anatomy of the mermaid to consider.
- If it has side effects or a different design when in saltwater or freshwater please include it.
- If possible include an image to help me imagine it better.

Feel free to edit my grammar and the tag to the appropriate one, though I appreciate it if this is not removed when you edit it, give others a chance to know that they are welcome to fix or edit this if there's still some mistakes left.

Comment: It's nice that you explicitly let other users edit your grammar. However please try to learn from those edits and prevent them. After more than 70 questions it should be clear that it's "I", not "i", "I'm" and not "im", "don't" and not "dont".

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica whats the difference? just because i make more 70 questions desnt mean i suddenly know proper english, though i appreciate your correction but iam not here to learn english i just want answer to my question.

Comment: We are also here to answer questions, not to correct other's English. Writing proper English is a way of showing some respect to those who read your questions. And since you see the edits which are done, you can just follow what the edits do, since they are pretty consistent on all your questions.

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica hence i say "feel free" no enforcement there, you can leave it as is if dont want to. my engrish is broken anyway i better leave it to the profesional, and you cant please anyone anyway, at least i try to make it readable enough. and i do copy paste some word from the edit though if it close with the context. besides why theres a feature for others to edit it if thats not its purpose?

Comment: You say "what's the difference ?"  well I think a point about spelling here is that while we try to be tolerant as obviously there are non-native English users here, it is still a turn off to people and it may decrease the number of people prepared to read and answer your questions.  It can even get downvotes from some people.  So it's in your interest to get as much right as possible.

Comment: @StephenG meh, i already get downvote anyway, you cant please anyone. and i have enough in trying, i more want answer than pleasing the english reader, if they need proper english before they want to answer then so be it. because i cant provide that.

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica i do not write "proper english" in my questions, or answers, i make mistakes, i get lazy sometimes, but putting "i" instead of "I" still gets the same message across, if i was writing an english assignment i would write properly, but its not necessary in all situations

Comment: Most people consider it common courtesy to use language (English, in this case, properly). Refusing to do so is, frankly, rude. If you can't be bothered to take a little care and courtesy expressing yourself, why should we be bothered to do so?

Comment: @Topcode, nobody is expecting a Shakespeare level for posts here. I am the first one to drop bloopers on my posts. On the other hand, the same effort put in writing the same text every time to allow edits instead of fixing small stuff like those I mentioned, plus going in just half an hour from "English" to "Engrish" tells me that it is not a mere fact of lacking skill, but rather a willful lack of respect.

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica this is offtopic topic anyway, and how much i need to give you respect, i upvote your comment because as i say i appreciate  your correction including every comment here and i do edit it you know, Topcode even point out how irrelevant that is, this is the kind of  first world problem that cost monica get kick out. this is worldbuilding SE not writhing SE or english SE which i can see a legit comment like this.

Comment: @Matthew why you assume i want others to write english properly? as long the message is conveyed or understandable its already ok in my book, so no need to get bothered by it.

Comment: I'm not talking about others making an effort to use proper English in their answers, I'm talking about making an effort to *answer*, period (or even *read* the question for that matter). As L.Dutch mentions, you're exhibiting "a willful lack of respect". WB is not about us doing the work *for* you, it is about *you* doing the work and only coming to WB when you are stuck. If you can't be bothered to make an effort — and that *includes* trying to write properly — why should we want to do anything for you?

Comment: Put differently, how would *you* feel if I willfully butchered *your* native language and refused to accept correction or make *any* attempt to not do so? If I insisted that using your language properly was "a pointless waste of time"? It's disrespectful of your culture and your time. With an attitude like that, would *you* feel any respect for me, or desire to help me however it is that I need help? Again, *this is common social courtesy*.

Comment: @Matthew then dont, no matter what you say it doesnt change my english and grammar suck, not only that the way english is, very different compare to my language so it quite alien concept to me.  it happen alot in my country because we get lots of tourist that even butcher the language name and no one care including me because we know they are not there to learn our language just try to communicate we dont fuss like english nazi regarding "i" and "I"

Comment: @Matthew i mean "grammar nazi" there

Comment: @Matthew oh yeah also i do make effort, try to make it readable as best as i can and i do try to search some stuff regarding this question, even edit it into the question there not long after L.Dutch say so but i dont see the difference and it seems to me neither the readers, beside even saying "thank you" is  frown here, even in meta theres a discussion about "this place is not mean to socialize or know each other" something like that, so i dont know regarding the social courtesy it feel messed up but even so i do say i appreciate the L.Dutch comment even upvote all the comment and answer.

Answer (score 3):

Deep water rivers were the original toilets for the merfolk.  These streams of faster moving water (often quite cold) would remove any waste products from the area.  The traditions of the primitive Merfolk requires calls in a particular sonar pulse to be emitted down stream just prior to use, so that others can get out of the stream before it "warms up".

As the Merfolk civilization evolved, they began engineering private rooms built along the paths of these streams with an appropriately located hole in the side facing the stream.  Vacuum effect from the passing stream would constantly pull water through these underwater outhouses, allowing the occupants to relieve themselves without soiling their garments.

Once the folk developed plumbing and pump technology, the final modern mertoilet was invented.  This device, which is installed in almost every merhome, appears very similar to a human male urinal but with a larger hole.  A valve, which usually remains closed to conserve vacuum pressure, is controlled by a lever near the top.  Just before the user relieves themselves, they push the lever, opening the valve and starting the vacuum induced current within the private bathroom.  Once the current is strong enough, waste products are produced and evacuated into the plumbing network.

The plumbing network itself is almost identical to the human equivalent with the exception that it move massively larger quantities of water at a significantly higher rate and pressure.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to assume a few things about mermaid culture. They live in harmony with nature and respect their place in the food chain, cycle of life etc. They cultivate some sort of underwater plants for their own consumption or as food for livestock.

The poop would be used specifically to fertilize these crops. The toilet would be more of a composter setup similar to a waterless sawdust toilet. A layer of sand is placed or thrown over the poop after use to cover it, and to get it to sink, and the contents later harvested for use on crops. No flushing required. A fast growing broad-leafed plant is grown near the receptacle, potted plant style, and used to clean-up.

The "seat" would be an upward incline that the user lays on, face down, with handles on the sides to be able to stabilize and hold themselves up next to the opening without using the tail. Using the tail would stir up too much water around the toilet.

If technology allows, a constant negative pressure would be activated, during use, inside the collection area and make sure everything got pulled in and the excess water entering is filtered, waste collected, sanitized and water returned to the surrounding environment.

Depending on the overall setting, ocean water is dirty anyway, and may not need to be 100% sanitized, just solids collected, and excess water expelled away from the users environment.

Comment: Your merfolk are better behaved than those I described in my answer.  Well done!  +1

Answer (score 1):

Mermaids evolved in an environment where there was no need to conserve water--thus one would expect feces to be fairly liquid.

If I were building a toilet for such a creature I would use a suction device, akin to what astronauts use aboard the ISS for urine.